# Scons Include Directory Static?

Tags: scons

Is there a way to specify a file, rather than a string when passing parameters?

```
env = Environment(LIBPATH = "include") # problem

Export("env")

SConscript("somepath")

...

# SConscript #

Import("env")

env.Program( ... )
```

The problem is it'll use the directory of the SConscript, which does not have the "include" folder. I've noticed that some of the objects returned (env.Program()) that don't have this problem. When doing a `out = env.Program(...)` in the SConscript `print out` it'll return one path, then in the SConstruct it'll return another path that is the correct one fixing the relative path.

Comment: In addition to my answer below, I suggest you take a look at the UserGuide of SCons http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html . Just read a bit, to get a better feel for how things are supposed to work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't specify variables like LIBPATH/CPPPATH, which change for every module (library/executable), in the top-level SConstruct. Setup the compiler/linker flags that should get used by **every** module, and then Export() the environment as before.

Then, in the SConscript, use:

```
Import('env')

localEnv = env.Clone()
localEnv.Append(LIBPATH=['include'])

localEnv.Program( ... )
```

, where "include" is the relative path to the lib folder from the directory of the current SConscript.
This will make maintenance of single modules much easier, and also provides a better starting point for things like variant builds.

Comment: Well i am using a variant build in a way, `root/build/win32/SConscript` then i have my include being `root/include`, i get what you are trying to say though. Does this go against the ideology completely? As i don't see the include path ever having to change. And the include path is the same for every build system i am going to write, `root/build/linux/SConscript` and `root/build/darwin/SConscript` etc... So defining `../../include/` in each of those just seems redundant as they will all need that path.

Comment: I guess you're searching for the "#" notation then. Whenever you specify a path, prepending a "#" means: "Start relative to the folder where the top-level SConstruct resides in.". For your example "#include" should then always resolve to "root/include"...